# Forward to a static html page from Controller

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

My spring mvc application has one single ContentNegotiatingViewResolver that defines JsonView for rendering json resonses:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="world.domination.test"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.secondmarket.connector.springmvc.MappingJacksonJsonViewEx"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The whole application sits on root url "myapp". Everything works as I need.

The **first question** is: how to return a static html page when accessing a certain url? Say, when accessing Spring uri /myapp/test I would like to render an html page /TestStuff.html that resides in root webapp folder.

I went ahead and wrote a simple controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("test")
public class TestConnector {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate tpl;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get() {
        return "/TestStuff.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String post(@RequestParam("url") String url, @RequestParam("data") String data) {
        return tpl.postForObject(url, data, String.class, new HashMap<String, Object>());
    }
}
```

The get() method is supposed to tell Spring to render a TestStuff.html, but instead I get
an error saying that the view with name "/TestStuff.html" is missing.

The **second question** is how to avoid the necessity to put extension to the URL. In my example, when I use **/myapp/test** instead of **/myapp/test.html** my ContentNegotiatingViewResolver uses a json view that renders {} (empty curly braces)

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: From your configuration of `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` I can't understand what are you trying to achieve. This resolver is applicable when the same resource may be rendered in different representations. If some of resources are rendered in JSON, while others are HTML, another configuration of resolvers is needed.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of returning "/TestStuff.html" from your controller, try returning "redirect:/TestStuff.html".

Another option is to create and register a view resolver for your static pages.  Perhaps something like this:

```xml
<bean id="staticViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/static/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: This "redirect:/TestStuff.html" is working just fine (at least with Spring MVC 3.1.1)... It's simpler than having to add viewResolver since I have one already defined for all my JSP pages.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use InternalResourceViewResolver combined with mvc:view-controller tag (see appropriate Spring Reference Manual for details). Just include the following into your application context XML file (in this case your static file TestStuff.html will be located in /WEB-INF/static-pages directory):

```
<bean>
    <bean id="staticPagesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/static-pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
</bean>

<mvc:view-controller path="/test" view-name="TestStuff"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

tutorialspoint has a good complete example of this:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_static_pages_example.htm